# Find all value of a such that the linear system is consistnet for any value of b1, b2 and b3

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1\\-a&-1&a\\a^2&1&-a\end{bmatrix}x=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix}$

(a)Find all value of a such that the linear system is consistnet for any value of b1, b2 and b3.

---

I have checked the determinant of the system matrix. The det=a$^3$-2a$^2$+a. I know that the system have unique solution iff det$\ne$0 (when a$\ne$0 or a$\ne$1). However, the system still can be consistent if there is infinity many solution. I just don't know whether a=0 or a=1 is consistent in this case. Also, how to write down the answer with a proper step?

Comment: Finding all values $a$ such that you have a solution for any $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ is the same as wanting the matrix to be surjective (as a linear mapping). However it is $3 \times 3$ (it is linear mapping $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$), thus is the same as the matrix being invertible. Therefore your $det \neq 0$ is enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an $a$ for which the determinant is zero, then the matrix does not have full rank, and its column space is not all of $\mathbb R^3$. Therefore in *each* such case there is *some* set of values of $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ that makes the system inconsistent.

Concretely, for each of $a=0$ and $a=1$ you can take $(b_1,b_2,b_3)=(0,1,0)$ as an example that proves that your system is not consistent for *all* value of $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$.

Comment: Yeah! I understand your thought because I have this idea also. The major problem is the term "for any value of b1, b2 and b3". And also, I don't know how to present this idea in a proper format (steps).
Thank you so much!!

Comment: x @Icy: Which problem do you have with the phrase "for any value of $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$"? As soon as you show there is _some_ value of the $b$s where the system is _inconsistent_, this is the same as saying that the system is _not_ "consistent for any value of the $b$s".